# Python - Draw text or image on top of background image with relative positioning using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow  to put some texts/images on top of another image.

My code looks like this :

```
header = Image.open("header.jpg")
header1 = header.resize((670, 280), Image.ANTIALIAS)
foreground = Image.open("MyImage.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(header1)
header1.paste(foreground,(523,190), foreground)
draw.text((565, 210), "TEXT1",  
font=ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", 14), fill=
(232,43,123,255))
draw.text((535, 221), "TEXT2", 
font=ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf", 55), fill=
(232,43,123,255))
header1.save('Images/header_final.png')
```

My issue is I am using images from different sizes (and I do not want to resize to not lose quality) so I would want the positionning of my text to be always relative to my background image. IE : 30% to the left and 50% down.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ! In case anyone is wondering, I added :

```
point = ( int(header.width * 0.5), int(header.height * 0.5))
header1.paste( foreground, point )
```

It now works :)